# apache-nifi: workflow reuse and global settings

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a processor which is able to send email ( putEmail ) and I need to use it in several workflows. Is here a good way to reuse the same processor without cloning it?

Answer (score 1):

All of the properties on PutEmail support expression language so you can attach everything like the hostname, port, message, etc, into flow file attributes and then reference them in a single PutEmail like ${message}.

Comment: Is there a way to use workflows like "subs"?  Define once use many ?

Comment: You can export any number of configured processors + their relationships as a template, and then re-import the template as many times as you want to the same (or other) workflows.

You can also route multiple incoming connections to the same instance of the `putEmail` processor and rely on the attributes to be referenced using Expression Language as Bryan noted.